# Asynchronous Data is not setting in AngularJS run function from $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to set a value in angular run function from the service. 
The value is not setting in session storage for the first time load.
when i reload the url second time the value will be available. Please help me to resolve this issue

```
appName.run(function($rootScope, $state, $window, testSerivces) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if ($window.sessionStorage.getItem('loginID') === null) {
      testSerivces.login().then(function(response) {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('loginID', response.data.profile.id);
      }, function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }).finally(function() {

      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Add your state table for UI-router. Also what version of UI-Route are you using?

Comment: Is `$stateChangeStart` emitted when the page initially loads?

Comment: georgeawg @ I am using angular-ui-router@version v0.4.2.

Comment: Pytth @ $stateChangeStart is emitting

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this behaviour because you are sending an `async` request while calling `testSerivces.login()` and meanwhile the `State Change` will keep going. i.e,  the `testSerivces.login()` is happening in background while `State Change` is continuing it's propagation. So, You have to stop the event and wait for the service to resolve and then continue. Changing your code to

```
appName.run(function($rootScope, $state, $window, testSerivces) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if ($window.sessionStorage.getItem('loginID') === null) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent Propgation
        testSerivces.login().then(function(response) {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('loginID', response.data.profile.id);
        $state.go(toState, toParams); //Start Propogation Again
      }, function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }).finally(function() {

      });
    }
  });
});
```

Will do the trick. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Anees for the quick reply.  The value is setting now but I can see multiple login service request is going to the server.

Comment: I have fixed the multiple service call issue. its due to some of the wrong configuration of stateRouter. Thanks for the solution